# How to enable/disable "org.eclipse.ui.editors" extension in run time

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am using "org.eclipse.ui.editors" extension point in my application and i want this extension point to be enable/disable based on certain condition at run time.

Is there any way by which i can disable/enable this extension in run time?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know of any way to disable an editor. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: i have to enable for some type of projects and disable for some

Comment: Why do you _have to enable for some type of projects and disable for some_? Could you give a concrete example where that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

I have one possibility in mind but not sure if it is matching to your use case.
You may use your own Content Type, and in the describer of the content type you can check for whatever conditions. For instance which project it is part of. It could work if the InputSream given to org.eclipse.core.runtime.content.IContentDescriber.describe(InputStream, IContentDescription) is a FileInputStream (to be checked)

Regards,